# Units of measurement and the t-statistic

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, units

Consider a case in which we want to examine the effect of house value on homeupkeep  expenditure  using  linear  regression  model,  where  dependent  variable  y  is  the  upkeepexpense and independent variable x is home value.  Suppose that units of y and x are both in
US dollar.  Let $b_{1}$ be the slope estimate and $t_{1}$ be the t-statistic value in testing $H_{0}: β_{1}= 0$.Now we convert both y and x into Canadian dollar.  Let $b_{1}^{*}$ be the new slope estimate and $t_{1}^{*}$ be the t statistic value.  Show that $t_{1}^{*}$ = $t_{1}$

Comment: Observe that $ax/ay = x/y$, and think about how that might apply to the formula for calculating the t-statistic.

Comment: I'm more confused about the effect of the change in units on the standard error of $\beta_{1}$

Comment: The standard error is in the same units as the underlying values.

Comment: So if $a$ was the scalar representing the change to canadian dollars, it would be $t_{1}^{*}$ = $\frac{b_{1}^{*}}{se(b_{1}^{*})}$ = $\frac{ab_{1}}{ase(b_{1})}$ = $\frac{b_{1}}{se(b_{1})}$ = $t_{1}$ ???

Comment: Try it out in a concrete example: for instance, compute a t-statistic for a difference in lengths in meters and centimeters.  What happens?  Suppose, say, the observed difference in means is one meter with a one meter standard error.  In centimeters, that's an observed difference of 100 cm with a 100 cm SE.